# how to apply select2 in Yii2 dropdown list

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2, jquery-select2

In yii2 basic ActiveForm i have added a drop-down list and in it used the "options" array to add my attributes .i want to add select2 in my drop-down but it is not working .i have searched on web and found this method of "options" array i have used below but still its showing no output in the view

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
     <div class="form-group form-material floating" data-plugin="formMaterial">
       <div class="example"> <b role="presentation"></b>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'corporation_status')->dropDownList(Yii::$app->appstatues->status,['options'=>['class'=>'form-control','prompt'=>'abc','data-plugin'=>'select2']])->label('Stat'); ?>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use [kartik's select2 widget](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2)

Answer (score 0):

Use extension https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2

many good extensions is there too:
http://demos.krajee.com/

Comment: can't we just do it by using "data-plugin"=>'select2' anywhere within options array? will it be not the right method to do ?

Comment: The right way to do it is to use a Yii2 wrapper for the JS library Select2 (Kartik's one is the most used). `data-plugin` wont work unless you have further logic we dont know about. You could initiate Select2 on elements with that attribute yourself, but the wrapper is too nice not to use it, its used by a lot of people and famous wrappers are usually well-maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for "select2" to be added to your drop-down list do the following steps:
Add following css and js files to your "AppAsset":

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js
```

and in the form field add 'data-plugin'=>'select2' like this:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'corporation_status')->dropDownList(Yii::$app->appstatues->status,['prompt' => 'hello','data-plugin'=>'select2','class'=>'form-control'])->label('Status'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to install kartik\select2 widget for yii2

```
php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 "@dev"
```

Then to use the widget.

```
//Include kartik\select2 Class
use kartik\select2\Select2;

// Normal select with ActiveForm & model
echo $form->field($model, 'corporation_status')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => Yii::$app->appstatues->status,
    'options' => ['prompt' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
```